# ksh not find by bash in my cygwin installation but present in the folder bin/ksh with a lnk extension

Tags: cygwin

I have installed cygwin on my windows XP desktop on C:. It works fine except when I launch a .ksh. I had this error message :

```
bash: ./xxx.ksh: /bin/ksh : Bad interpreter:No such file or directory
```

I 've looked in the /bin folder with ls -al ksh and I found ksh.exe.lnk (a shortcut in my windows explorer. The target of this shortcut exists on my filesystem - pdksh.exe). 
I 've changed in my xxx.ksh

```
#!/bin/ksh
```

in

```
#!/bin/pdksh
```

And it works fine, but that's a ponctual solution...

Comment: None of my dictionaries include "ponctual". What does it mean?

Comment: punctual seems to be the right word, sorry english is not my native language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you create the symbolic link with cygwin, or did you create it as a shortcut in windows?  The links cygwin creates are compatible with windows, but shortcuts you create in windows aren't always compatible with cygwin unless you manually change them.  See [this](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-05/msg00451.html).

Use `ln -s /bin/pdksh.exe /bin/ksh` in cygwin to create the symlink ([see here](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2005-08/msg00546.html)).

**Edit:** fixed link direction

Comment: The shortcut is provided by the cygwin setup.

Comment: ln -s  /bin/pdksh.exe /bin/ksh is the right answer, thanks