# cygwin, PATH problem?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I run a .ksh containing a awk call. awk.exe and his shortcut awk is in /bin/awk, /bin is in the PATH environment variable. But when I try to launch awk, I have this error message :

```
bash: /usr/bin/awk: no such file or directory
```

Why didn't bash look for it in the /bin folder too?

edit : tar has the same rights, tar.exe is in /bin and can be listed in /usr/bin/, the exact same way than awk. Tar works fine whereas awk not.

Answer (score 1):

Does the ksh script explicitly define the path to awk? It could be via a variable ( `AWK=/usr/bin/awk`, invoked by `$AWK`). Try running `which awk` and `alias awk`, too.

**Edit**

Cygwin install process actually sets up `/usr/bin` as a hardlink to `/bin`. (Do `ls -li /usr/` and `ls -li /` and you'll see the `bin` folders have the same inode number. Also, browse to the /usr/bin folder in windows explorer and you'll see it's empty.)

Your PATH is probably fine, but probably has `/usr/bin` before `/bin`, so it's finding awk via that route first.

Looking at your [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/210839/ksh-not-find-by-bash-in-my-cygwin-installation-but-present-in-the-folder-bin-ksh), I think you might have a similar, shortcut related issue here. I tried renaming my `awk.exe` to `dawk.exe` in windows and then set up a shortcut called `awk.exe` pointing to it. Running `awk` then gives me the same error you can see.  I had to force that issue, though; I think your Cygwin installation might be a bit broken, but it's hard to say how. Do you get similar errors from any other binaries?

Comment: /usr/bin/awk with which, awk not found with alias command

Comment: Even with the variable in the .ksh I 've got the error message : /usr/bin/sh: /usr/bin/awk: No such file or directory

Comment: I've just remembered something about Cywgin. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

You should try an echo $PATH when you are in the korn shell. It will tell you the search path that is being used to find programs.

Alan